# Magento 2 how to get info_buyRequest in rest result rest/V1/orders/105"

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

Hi can any one tell me how to get addition information (info_buyrequest) in rest api result
https://mainwebsite.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/$order_id.
but here not getting product options getting remaining data

```
$order_id=42678;
$accessToken = "accesstoken";
$setHeaders = array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Authorization:Bearer ' . $accessToken);
   $ch = curl_init("https://website.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/$order_id");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHeaders);

   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    echo '<pre>';
//    echo '************************************************** Order **************************************************************';
    print_r($result);
```

i need below info in order rest api result how to get

```
 [product_options] => Array
        (
            [aw_gc_amount] => 100.00
            [aw_gc_sender_name] => Aaron, Amy and Anna
            [aw_gc_recipient_name] => Don and Naomi Hazlett
            [aw_gc_headline] =>
            [aw_gc_message] => Enjoy 
            [aw_gc_delivery_date] =>
            [aw_gc_delivery_date_timezone] =>
            [aw_gc_type] => 2
            [aw_gc_created_codes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => F3VDD9S7K09JVHOP
                )

            [info_buyRequest] => Array
                (
                    [uenc] => 
                    [product] => 8680
                    [aw_gc_amount] => 100.00
                    [aw_gc_recipient_name] => Don and Naomi Hazlett
                    [aw_gc_sender_name] => Aaron, Amy and Anna
                    [aw_gc_message] => Enjoy 
                    [qty] => 1
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `info_buyRequest` option is not exposed via the rest API, you will have to create your own method if you want to access it.